# how to scroll ToolStripMenuItem to specific item

Tags: c#

I have a big ToolStripMenuItem table  with vertical scroll bar. I would like to scroll to a specific item in this table

```
{

    MenuStrip strip = new MenuStrip();

    ToolStripMenuItem fileItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("&File");

    // Create an array of ToolStripMenuItems
    ToolStripMenuItem[] col = new ToolStripMenuItem[20];

    // Populate the list with menus named "Menu 1" through "Menu 4"
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        col[i] = new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu " + (i + 1));

        // Make first item checked
        if (i == 0)
        {
            col[i].Checked = true;
        }
    }

    // Create menu item containing icon and a collection
    ToolStripMenuItem collectionMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Collection", Image.FromFile("c:\\Arrow.png"), col);

    fileItem.DropDownItems.Add(collectionMenu);
    collectionMenu.DropDown.AutoSize = false;
    collectionMenu.DropDown.Height = 100;


    strip.Items.Add(fileItem);

    this.Controls.Add(strip);

}
```

I need to open dropdown and menu15 visible

[image]

Comment: you should be able to do Does your fileItem not support scrollcontrolintoview? according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx it should

Comment: I tried something like this collectionMenu.DropDown.ScrollControlIntoView(col[15]); but seems not working

Comment: Keep playing it looks to be there somewhere

Comment: You might want to consider making a separate dialog for selecting an item if you got that many of them...

Comment: actually, I give up I tried everything msdn ,google,stackoverflow and found no answer

Comment: If you realy find no solution, you can create at least a own `ToolStripDropDown`, but it requires much more effort. Create a `ToolStripDropDown` set a `Panel` as `Host` add a `ListView` to Panel, add your MenuItems as `ListViewItems`. And so on and so on. In `ListView` you can use `EnsureVisible(index)` to scroll to your Menu-Item